# Correct approach to solve turn based puzzles

Tags: python

I am simulating a game in python. It involves two players, each has a set of turns. Based on a hit or a miss, we decide if that player will get another turn.

I not able to craft this logic programmatically, here is what I have so far:

Let's simulate each player separately for the sake of simplicity

```
for coordinate in list_of_player1_moves:
    result = fire(coordinate[0], coordinate[1])
    #result is either a 'Hit' or a 'Miss'

for coordinate in list_of_player2_moves:
    result = fire(coordinate[0], coordinate[1])
    #result is either a 'Hit' or a 'Miss'
```

Now, in order to have individual turns for each player, I did:

```
turns = len(list_of_player2_moves) if len(list_of_player2_moves) > len(list_of_player1_moves) else len(list_of_player1_moves)

for turn in range(0, turns):
    r = move_player1(turn) #move player inturn calls fire()
    if(r == 'Hit'):
        break #start over, giving them another turn
    r = move_player2(turn)
    if r == 'Hit':
        #how do give player 2 another turn?
```

I am out of ideas on how to approach this further. Please suggest. Also please advice on alternative/better approaches.

Thanks!

Edit:

Sample Output for better understanding,

```
Player1 fires got miss
Player2 fires which got hit
Player2 fires which got miss
Player1 fires which got hit
Player1 fires which got hit
Player1 fires which got miss
Player2 fires which got miss
Player1 has no more missiles left to launch
Player2 fires which got hit
Player2 fires which got miss
Player1 has no more missiles left to launch
Player2 fires which got miss
Player1 has no more missiles left to launch
Player2 fires which got hit
Player2 fires which got miss
Player1 no more missiles left to launch
Player2 fires which got hit
Player2 won the battle
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem description is a bit ambiguous, so I am assuming that

1. Every time a player hits another player, he gets 1 more move
2. The game doesn't terminate until both of the players run out of moves

Thus I rewrote the function

```
counter = 0
no_of_player1_moves = len(list_of_player1_moves)
no_of_player2_moves = len(list_of_player2_moves)

while counter < no_of_player1_moves or counter < no_of_player2_moves:
    # won't terminate until both players run out of turns
    r = move_player1(turn)
    if(r == 'Hit'):
        no_of_player1_moves += 1 #if player1 hits, player1 gets 1 more turn
    r = move_player2(turn)
    if(r == 'Hit'):
        no_of_player2_moves += 1 #if player2 hits, player2 gets 1 more turn
    counter += 1
```

P.S:
Instead of your long statement

```
turns = len(list_of_player2_moves) if len(list_of_player2_moves) > len(list_of_player1_moves) else len(list_of_player1_moves)
```

You can simply use

```
turns = max(len(list_of_player2_moves),len(list_of_player1_moves))
```

Edit:

```
no_of_player1_moves = len(list_of_player1_moves)
no_of_player2_moves = len(list_of_player2_moves)

while no_of_player1_moves>0 or no_of_player2_moves>0:
    # won't terminate until both players run out of turns
    while move_player1(turn)=="Hit" and no_of_player1_moves!=0:
        no_of_player1_moves -= 1
    while move_player2(turn)=="Hit" and no_of_player2_moves!=0:
        no_of_player2_moves -= 1
```

This would probably solve your problem, but the design doesn't scale well (imagine if you have 10 players, you wouldn't want to write it 10 times).

For that, I would suggest creating a Player object, and placing them in a list, then keep cycling through the list (nested while loop) until all players run out of moves. There is probably a better solution out there too (even compared to this), but that would at least be scalable.

Comment: I need consecutive turns, perhaps the sample output will help, https://bpaste.net/show/661190d04e57

Comment: edit to solve the issue from how it seems from your output.

Comment: How do I increments the turn now?

Comment: You dont need the increment the turns anymore (unless you need to keep track) because it will keep running till it hits 0. The move_player executes in the while clause during the checking.